# sales_order_grid join with sales_order_item

Tags: magento2, php

I extend function that return the order collection:

```
protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $arrItems = [];
        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
            $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
        }

  return $arrItems;
}
```

`$arrItems['items']` this array return orders.

I want to join this with **sales_order_item** on the condition on **sales_order_grid.entity_id=sales_order_item.order_id.**
Any one help me please, am new in Magento 2.

Comment: what specific output do you need?

Comment: i want to change the grand_total that shown in order grid.
i want to calculate(sum) row_total_incl_tax from sales_order_item table where seller_id=1;
seller_id is my custom attribute in sales_order_item.
kindy anyone help me